# Connections between wordpress and android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a project that needs to have registration and login info from a website, I'm new to android studio so I don't have a clue how to do it or if it's possible.

What I need is, when the user opens the app it sends him to the website and login/register, after that if it was approved it go back to the app and continue there any idea how to do that?

I've looked many YouTube videos and here too but didn't get my answer yet.

Comment: you need to create login api and then using that pass your credentials from android activity to api using volley or similar library.

Comment: Would you kindly give me an example